# Problem with intersection table

Tags: mysql, php

I seem to have came to a problem which I am having trouble solving, possibly because I have misunderstood intersections properly(or perhaps I shouldn't even use intersections for the goal).

If we have a year table and use its primary key id in our intersection table to link to one actors primary key id, How can we populate the actors_nickname table before hand using one primary key id (to group together the rows)? which we then use after to populate the intersection table?

**year**

```
+---------+------+---------+
| year_id | year | created |
+---------+------+---------+
|    22   | 2000 | 01-01-01|
|    33   | 2044 | 01-01-01|
+---------+------+---------+
[----PK---]
```

**intersection**

```
+-----------+---------+
| actors_id | year_id |
+-----------+---------+
|     1     |    22   |
|     2     |    44   |
+-----------+---------+
[---------PK----------]
```

**actor_nicknames**

```
+-----------+----------+---------+
| actor_id | nickname | created |
+-----------+----------+---------+
|     1     |  batman  | 01-01-01|
|     1     |   bond   | 02-02-11|
|     1     | peter pan| 14-11-14|
|     1     |  dexter  | 22-08-10|
+-----------+----------+---------+
[--------UNIQUE--------]
```

This is the desired result above, However if I was to insert rows into actor_nicknames, we would actually get actors_id = 1,2,3,4, which is useless to us in the intersection table as we need these rows grouped by the same ID.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a `JOIN`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html for the official docs. JOINs can be used to create a dynamical rowset based on several tables.

The exact SQL depends on your current tables. I think you did not describe all your tables in your question.

By the way, if you actually mean an SQL `INTERSECT`, that is not available in MySQL.